# Improving Movie Filtering in ASP.NET Core OpenAPI Project: A Cleaner Approach

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Good afternoon! I'm writing my pet project in **asp.net core(mvc) using the open api**. My project is a movie watching website. I am currently working with getting data from the api and have a problem with the correct construction of a function to get a collection of movies by filter(I just don't know how to do it right). I came up with the next option:

```
// Example

// Accepts parameters for filtering.
// Returns a request with the configured filters.
private string GetUrlWithFilter(List<MoviePartial.Genre> genres, List<string> years, List<MoviePartial.Rating> ratings, List<MoviePartial.Country> countries)
{
    string urlExpression = $"{_httpHelperKinopoisk.RequestUrl}/movie/search?";

    foreach (var genre in genres)
    {
        urlExpression = urlExpression + $"genres.name={genre}&";
    }
    
    // ...
    
    foreach (var countrie in countries)
    {
        urlExpression = urlExpression + $"premiere.name={countrie}&";
    }
    
    return urlExpression;
}
// Example

public async Task<string> GetMoviesByFilter(string urlWithFilter, int page=1, int limit=10)
{
    string url = $"{urlWithFilter}page={page}&limit={limit}&";
    
    var response = await _httpHelperKinopoisk.HttpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
    return response;
}
```

But this option doesn't look very good.

The code works, but it looks terrible and I want to ask you for advice on how better to do it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because according to the OP, the code works, but is 'ugly'. This is considered off-topic on Stack Overflow, but may be a good fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

`StringBuilder` is a more efficient way to construct strings then concatenating strings in a loop. Also you can create a model that represents your movie filters to improve readability and maintainability.

```
public class MovieFilters
{
    public List<MoviePartial.Genre> Genres { get; set; }
    public List<string> Years { get; set; }
    // Other filter properties...
}
```

Then, adjust your method to accept this model:

```
private string GetUrlWithFilter(MovieFilters filters)
{
    var urlBuilder = new StringBuilder($"{_httpHelperKinopoisk.RequestUrl}/movie/search?");

    if (filters.Genres != null && filters.Genres.Any())
    {
        foreach (var genre in filters.Genres)
        {
            urlBuilder.Append($"genres.name={genre}&");
        }
    }
    // Add other filters similarly...

    return urlBuilder.ToString();
}
```